# Shapefile containing several fields with the same variable at different times. How to group them into a single field?

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes

I have a point shapefile that includes several (e.g 160) of fields with the mean temperature and wind speed [at each location] for different days. Ideally, I want to reduce the number of fields to only one for each variable, by grouping the corresponding data. For instance, what I was thinking to do, was to convert the corresponding values into strings and concatenate them into a long string, which I will store in a single field. What is the most efficient and elegant approach? Is it better to use a different data structure?

Please keep in mind that I have to use these data for plotting in matplotlib and also to be able to share the point shapefile and the temperature + wind speed data with others.

Comment: So what is the average summer temperature? Good luck answering that if all your data is concatenated in a string. The clean way would be to have a point layer (stationID, X, Y) and a table (stationID, date, temperature). You can then manipulate the data as you wish using queries (that do not modify the data structure)

Comment: 160 fields is 100-150 more than a shapefile ought to have. It's time to discover what databases can do with a proper database design and good normalization.

Answer (score -2):

Create new field then Use the field calculator create an expression